# template not displaying info -django

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I have no errors but my page wont show information from my template tagging. Please help!

models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
department_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
department_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,default = '')
department_location = models.CharField(max_length=255,default = '')
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',views.home,name='home'),

path('department',views.DepartmentClass.as_view(template_name='type/departmentdetails.html'),name='department'),

]
```

views.py

```
class DepartmentClass(TemplateView):

def departments(request):
    departments = Department.objects.all()
    print(departments)
    return render(request,'type/departmentdetails.html', {'departments':departments})
```

departmentdetails.html

```
                      {% for i in departments %}
                       <tr>
                            <td>{{i.department_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.department_location}}</td>
                       </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
```

the data i have saved on django/admin console wont show up on my webpage where is my code wrong please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

`views.py`

```
def departments(request):
    departments = Department.objects.all()
    print(departments)
    return render(request,'type/departmentdetails.html', {'departments':departments})
```

`urls.py`

```
from . import views
    
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('department/',views.departments name='department'),]
```

`departmentdetails.html`

```
  {% for department in departments %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{department.department_name}}</td>
       <td>{{department.department_location}}</td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

This is one way to achieve this via function-based view. also make sure your url is included in project root url config. you can check here for more how to configure your url [django urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path)